# How to refactor Events in WPF?

Tags: wpf, events, xaml, resources, refactoring

I have multiple textboxes with TextChanged events bound to the same handler

```
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextChanged" Value="TextBox_TextChanged" />
         </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

I know the code above is invalid, but it is something similar to what I want to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can put the `TextBoxBase.TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"` attribute on the common container element of all of your text boxes, for ex:

```
<StackPanel TextBoxBase.TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged">
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want it in a style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
</Style>
```